# googleVis minimizes text and tables in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, minimize, googlevis

I'm trying to make a report with R markdown, kable and googleVis. It almost works perfectly fine, the tables and graphs are produced. However, if I try to put graphs AND tables in the rmarkdown, the tables and any text that is not a header is minimized, making them hard to read.

If I only put tables in the markdown file, the tables are a nice size. I would like to know why the tables and text are minimized when graphs from googleVis are added and how I can prevent this.

The following is a reproducible code:

````
```{r results='asis'}
   values1 <- c(36, 9, 21, 16)
   values2 <- c(5, 5, 0 ,6)
   variables <- c("Total", "Var1", "Var2", "Var3")

   table <- data.frame(variables, values1, values2)
   kable(table, caption = "example table")
```

```{r results='asis'}
  values3 <- c(1, 3, 0, 9)
 values4 <- c(4, 6, 3 ,2)
 pievariables <- c("ISV", "TAO", "PRR", "AV")

 piechart <- data.frame(pievariables, values3, values4)

 Pie <- gvisPieChart(piechart[,1:2], options=list(title='example pie',
                                                      width = 400, 
                                                      height = 400,
                                                      pieSliceText='label'))
 Pie
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `Pie` with `print(Pie, "chart")`:

```
Pie <- gvisPieChart(piechart[,1:2], options=list(title='example pie',
                                                 width = 400, 
                                                 height = 400,
                                                 pieSliceText='label'))

print(Pie, "chart)
```

this should do the work

Comment: Thank you very much, that did indeed solve the problem. Could you also explain why it works if you specifiy "chart" and doens't if you just write "Pie", so I know why it happens?

Comment: You're very welcome. The thing is that if you add "chart" into the print function then only the chart component of the HTML object is written otherwise you load everything (the header, chart, caption and footer) of the HTML and this actually cause the problem with knitr.

However, alternatively you can also use the gvisTables to do more fancy tables than kable. In your case: print(gvisTable(table), "chart")

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I see now that with the header and footer a new html page is made (<html> <body> and </body> </html>) for the chart. That would cause a bit of trouble. Again, thanks very much.